# JavaScript ReGeX: replace matched strings in between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex, mathjax

I am allowing users to type in BBCodes that convert to MathJax; however, there's a problem, as you can see below.

```
function chatFormat(text){
    text = text.replace('\\', '');
    text = text.replace(/\[f\](.+?)\/(.+?)\[\/f\]/igm, '\\( \\frac{\\text{$1}}{\\text{$2}} \\)');
    text = text.replace(/\[eq\](.+?)\[\/eq\]/igm, '\\( $1 \\)');
    text = text.replace(/(.+?)\^(.+?)/igm, '\\( $1^{\\text{$2}} \\)');
    text = text.replace(/\[sqrt\](.+?)\[\/sqrt\]/igm, '\\( \\sqrt{\\text{$1}} \\)');

    return text;
}
```

Works almost fine. It converts the BBCodes into the appropriate commands flawlessly; however, there is a problem if you begin to nest commands. e.g.:

If a user types in:

`[eq]15^2 = [sqrt]225[/sqrt][/eq]`

It will be converted to:

`\( 15^{2} = \( \sqrt{225} \) \)`

```
             ^            ^
             |            |
             |            |
             |            |
              HOW TO AVOID
```

How can I avoid the extra `\(`and `\)` when they nest BBCodes, like the square root command inside the `[eq]` bbcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that will likely be very hard with regular expressions, because you can't use them to match arbitrarily nested patterns (see e.g. [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns) ). If you do need this kind of sophisticated nested parsing, you're better of writing a real parser... Or better yet, since BBCode is so common, using one that already exists. Here's one that looks fairly extensible and may suit your needs: https://github.com/patorjk/Extendible-BBCode-Parser

Comment: Sorry, which link do you feel needs to be better explained in the answer? The first points to a highly upvoted stackoverflow topic on this general matter (why regular expressions are inappropriate for parsing nested expressions), while the second link points to a library that could solve this specific problem.